# jquery .zoom is not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm using `.zoom`, [jquery zoom plugin](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/) for zooming the images and I'm using the code that given below.

```
$(this).wrap('<span class="idpzoom" style="display:inline-block;"></span>')
.css({
    display: 'block'
})
.parent()
.zoom({
    url: zoomImg,
    target: '#idp_zoomedimage',
    duration: 1
});
```

It is working in every browsers but not working only in IE7.

Comment: Jquery doesn't have `zoom` method. which plugin are you using?

Comment: http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/ i used this as reference

Comment: Seems the problem is actually in the way you are adding `span` element but not in zoom plugin. I am sure the problem is not related to zoom plugin though. Can you see any error in console?

Comment: But it is working in all the browsers including IE8 but not only in IE7

Comment: No error in the console

Answer (score 0):

Try this once and let me know:

```
$(this).wrap('<span class="idpzoom"></span>')
.show()
.parent()
.zoom({
    url: zoomImg,
    target: '#idp_zoomedimage',
    duration: 1
});
```

Comment: @user2642444 Is this happening in a table element?

Comment: No. I'm not using any table element.

Comment: #idp_zoomedimage is a div and in idpzoom class and adding css part as 'opacity:1 !important;
 display : inline-block;'

Comment: @user2642444 I am not sure then what could be the problem (I am trying though). BTW, `display: inline-block` doesn't work in IE7. I hope you tried exactly what I had shown above.

Comment: Now I tried by removing inline-block in my code but it remains the same.

Comment: @user2642444 once try expanding the code, something like this http://jsfiddle.net/LHm8U/

Comment: @user2642444 Sorry, no idea.

Comment: Okay. Please suggest some other zoom plugin that work perfectly.

Comment: @user2642444 I don't know. (there are many plugins) I am 99% sure that this problem is not related to zoom plugin though. You can test by doing the same with other selected zoom plugin. Good luck :)